# How to randomly sample a set number of rows from a dataframe with a preset condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'Pic': ['D1', 'D1', 'D2', 'D2', 'D3', 'D3', 'D4', 'D4'], 'Rating': [42, 54, 61, 72, 43, 52, 91, 22], 'Pair': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
  Pic  Rating  Pair
0  D1      42     1
1  D1      54     2
2  D2      61     1
3  D2      72     2
4  D3      43     1
5  D3      52     2
6  D4      91     1
7  D4      22     2
```

I need to select a subset of 2 rows such that there are 2 unique values from the Pic column but if a value is randomly picked (say, 'D1' is picked from the column, Pic), it's the corresponding pair is picked as well (so the row with D1 would be picked that has Pair 1, and also D1 that has Pair 2).

I tried the following:

```
df_Selected= df.sample(n=2, random_state=2)
```

But I am not sure how to make sure that each value that is randomly selected from the 'Pic' column, also has its pair selected from the 'Pair' column. So if the following row is randomly picked:

```
   Pic  Rating  Pair
0  D1      42     1
```

I would also need the following row to be randomly picked:

```
       Pic  Rating  Pair
    0  D1      42     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import random

d = {'Pic': ['D1', 'D1', 'D2', 'D2', 'D3', 'D3', 'D4', 'D4'],
     'Rating': [42, 54, 61, 72, 43, 52, 91, 22],
     'Pair': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

random_pic_list = random.sample(df['Pic'].unique().tolist(), 2)

df_slice = df[df['Pic'].isin(random_pic_list)]

print(df_slice)

    Pic Rating  Pair
0   D1  42  1
1   D1  54  2
2   D2  61  1
3   D2  72  2
```

Comment: @Matthew Borish For some reason, there is an error that this code produces: TypeError: random_sample() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)

Comment: @piRSquared is there a way to control how many random choices are made with your suggestion? I tried varying it by using random.choices: df[df.Pic == random.choices(df.Pic.unique(), k=2)] but it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure you're entering the code correctly? I've just tried it again from the post and it works. Also, random.sample() takes 2 required args. https://pynative.com/python-random-sample/

Comment: @arkadiy I'm uncertain whether you want 2 distinct `Pic` values (thus 4 rows).  Or do you want 2 rows from a single randomly picked `Pic` value.  In the latter case, because there happens to be 2 rows per `Pic`, this exercise is trivial.